# When I call SaveChanges, nothing saved back to the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

```
        editableCustomers = _ctx.Customers.ProjectTo<EditableCustomer>().ToList();
        editableCustomers.First().Name = "changed";
        var customers = _ctx.Customers.ToList();
        Mapper.Map(editableCustomers, customers);

         _ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I  use Automapper to perform the mapping between the EF Entities(Customer in this case) and the Editable Model(EditableCustomer).
Why SaveChanges does not Work ?

Comment: Is this the code as is or did you edit it for the question? Because I don't understand why you are converting Customers to EditableCustomers and 3 lines down converting it back again.

Comment: Also are you getting any error messages on SaveChanges or anywhere else or does everything execute and you do not see any changes? Also do you have an Id or other primary key on your entities and can you use those to retrieve the correct object in the context?

Comment: ```customers``` is now just a list of detached models the context knows nothing about. You'll need to ```Attach``` them back to the context as ```Modified``` won't you?

Comment: I have WPF DataGrid that binded to List of Editable Customer.

Comment: I don't get any error..

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would use AutoMapper using:

```
var results = Mapper.Map<DestinationType>(source);
```

Or in your case

```
var results = Mapper.Map<Customer[]>(editableCustomers);
```

Also AutoMapper does not change the values in the context but merely converts objects from one form to another. It currently appears you are just converting objects and doing nothing with those objects afterwards. Also the context isn't aware of those changes.

Normally to save the changes I would rather use code like this:

```
var customer = _ctx.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == modifiedEditableCustomer.Id);
customer.Name = modifiedEditableCustomer.Name;

_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Where modifiedEditableCustomer is one of your EditableCustomer (you could loop through them).

Here is another way to iterate over the Customers and save the changed objects. If the object has changed (you'll need to determine this) then you can re-attach the object and set it's state to modified.

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    if (HasCustomerBeenModified(customer))
    {
        _ctx.Customers.Attach(customer)
        _ctx.Entry(customer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: why you don't use FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: @MohammadDaliri normally when I check for IDs I expect that the ID I have is a valid one and if I can't find it in the database that is exceptional enough to warrant an exception. In some cases rather than the standard linq message I prefer to use a SingleOrDefault and check for the null manually to throw a custom exception with a better message. As for using FirstOrDefault rather than SingleOrDefault, FirstOrDefault will be valid if it finds more than one entity with the same ID which should never happen. I want to know in those cases. But ultimately all of this is a matter of style...

Comment: ```var results = Mapper.Map<Customers>(editableCustomers);``` wouldn't it be ```var results = Mapper.Map<Customer[]>(editableCustomers);``` or ```var results = Mapper.Map<List<Customer>>(editableCustomers);``` ?

Comment: @pmcilreavy You're entirely right. Thanks for spotting that, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have WPF DataGrid that binded to List of Editable Customer, how to know which one Has Modified ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Automapper, you can use this way:

```
        var editableCustomers = _ctx.Customers.ProjectTo<Customer>().ToList();
        editableCustomers.First().Name="changed";
        var customers = _ctx.Customers.ToList();
        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            customer.Name = editableCustomers.First(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).Name;
        }
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, this worked, but how to do this in most performance way?